# How to open external console window in intellij platform on run?

Tags: intellij-idea, clion, jetbrains-ide

I'm write console application on C++ and wanna use CLion (JetBrains). But when i'm runned exe, it use internal IDE console output. Is there way to say to CLion that it should use cmd.exe directly without internal console?

Comment: Did you find out, want to do this too?

Answer (score -1):

I don't think there is a way to use cmd.exe (default command-line interpreter), while using CLion (JetBrains). But you can amend setting to have CLion console in a separate window.

1. Press Alt+F12.
   Console will appear at the bottom.
2. In the right top corner of console there is a "gear" symbol ⚙️ (settings), click on it.
3. Go to "View mode" and select "Float".

Comment: This does not AT ALL answer the OPs question. Why is this answer still here? You tell people how they can make a widget float - which is not an external console!